# Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fc3c90dc98e

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, python-3.6, invalid-pointer

Got this error on an ubuntu server (100GB RAM) in anacondas py3.6 installation after it opened multiple files this way in a for loop (7 files * 4GB):

> temp_df = pd.read_csv(datafolder + str(file), encoding="ISO-8859-1", delimiter=';',low_memory=False)

this is the error, it appeared after i set

> low_memory=False

Doesnt happen when low_memory = True

> *** Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fc3c90dc98e ***

Anyone ideas? Thanks

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/topik/issues/71 it seems to be a problem of anaconda. I have however no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I am facing this issue as well when I was prompted to set low_memory=False. The csv file i am reading into pandas is 16 Gb though.

Comment: is your `num_workers=0`? (mine is and I am getting the error, where else could it be trying to open multiple files?)

Comment: related link: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/segmentation-fault/23489/17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is caused due to multiple threads performed parallelly when opening a file , this causes sometimes segmentation fault as well.
As you said your file consist of 4 gb each so multiple threads which are executed parallelly to read up your file is causing the issue.

[image: ScreenSHot]

[image: Invalid Pointer]

Comment: meaning pandas or anaconda is parallelizing the process? and low_memory = False triggers this?

Comment: Yes,All this is because of that

Comment: I am seeing an error even when `num_workers=0`...is that expected?

Comment: is this an error due to GPU or due to normal RAM?