# How to fix Django / python free(): invalid pointer?

Tags: python, django

When I run the django manage.py app, I got free(): invalid pointer error.

Example:

```
>python manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
free(): invalid pointer
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

The django app is running fine but I'm trying to get rid off this message.

How can I fix this error or get more info to debug it?

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux (Ubuntu 20.04)
Django==2.2.28
with virtualenv
```

Comment: I also tried different versions of python using pyenv. But I got the same error.

Comment: I have the same django configuration on another server and the problem does not occurs.

Comment: Do you have any code using threading, etc.? Related: [Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fc3c90dc98e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607973/error-in-python-free-invalid-pointer-0x00007fc3c90dc98e)

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with same environment with same Django version and I ran the `check` command, which did not yield this problem. I assume it is an issue with Pytorch, as mentioned in here: **[GitHub issue #21018](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21018)**.

To resolve it, you can take the following steps (copy pasted from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363390/2696165)

---

> There is a known issue with importing both open3d and PyTorch. A few possible workarounds exist:
>
> (1) Some people have found that changing the order in which you import the two packages can resolve the issue, though in my personal testing both ways crash.
>
> (2) Other people have found compiling both packages from source to help.
>
> (3) Still others have found that moving open3d and PyTorch to be called from separate scripts resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying nuddra. But the project doesn't use pytorch.

Comment: Okay, but the idea is that there is a library or piece of code which uses C implementation underneath. You need to check why that code is causing this issue. The problem is not related to Python/Django. One more SO question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297524/c-free-invalid-pointer

Answer (score 1):

That's a C error related to memory freeing, probably due to a bug from some unpatched dependency package, since you're using an old Django version.

Some options:

- Check your project at [debug level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-check-fail-level):

  `python3 manage.py check --fail-level DEBUG`
- List your dependencies and look online for which one originates that error:

  `python3 -m pip freeze`
- Log files.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan but fail-level didn't get any result. What I am looking for is to find which library is returning the error. The app had 40 libraries installed :( If I just remove one of them, the manage.py will raise errors related to the library removal.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with external dependencies.

You can run the check command on a specific app:

```
    python manage.py check app1 app2 app3 

For Example:
    python manage.py check auth user myapp
```

Running on any specific database is also possible.

```
    python manage.py check --database default --database other
```

A few similar articles found:

https://github.com/duckietown/apriltags3-py/issues/1

https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/414

https://bugs.python.org/issue41335

Comment: Thanks RIcha but manage.py check works great. What I want is to find is which library is returning the free command.